# get webhook that triggered the AWS CodePipeline run

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-codepipeline

Background:

I'm planning on creating a Codepipeline that has multiple source actions within the initial source stage. Each source action is a GitHub repo that will have its own AWS CodePipeline webhook. Within the pipeline's next stage, I want to have an invoke action that will get the pipeline execution's webhook that triggered the pipeline run and set the input artifact for the downstream build stage to be the source action that is associated with the triggered webhook. For example, if repo A's webhook caused pipeline execution #1, then the invoke action will somehow identify that the repo A's webhook was the trigger and then pass repo A's output artifact to the downstream build stage.

Problem:

I haven't found a solution to get the Codepipeline webhook that triggered the pipeline run. Looking at the boto3 Codepipeline docs, the closest I've got was `list_webhooks` that identifies what pipeline the webhook is associated with but nothing in regards to if that webhook triggered Codepipeline execution ID 123.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [list_pipeline_executions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codepipeline.html#CodePipeline.Client.list_pipeline_executions) command should help you in this case. It provides you with CodePipeline execution summaries, where the first result is the **latest** execution ID. Each summary has a `trigger` attribute with information about how the execution was triggered. For a webhook it looks like this:

```
"trigger": {
    "triggerType": "Webhook",
    "triggerDetail": "arn:aws:codepipeline:<region>:<account-id>:webhook:<webhook-id>"
}
```

If your pipeline is likely to be running concurrently, make sure you get the **current** execution ID first so things do not get mixed up. You can do this with a one-liner in CodeBuild as suggested [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=753054).

Comment: ah I looked over that command on the docs. Thanks for the references and the tip @berenbums